# How to create a raster map in QGIS that includes the distance to the nearest road multiplied by another variable included in a vector file?

Tags: qgis, raster, proximity

I am using QGIS (v. 3.4). I have a vector file (.shp) with the main roads of my city including the average traffic load of each segment. I would like to create a map with the inverse distance to the nearest road multiplied by the traffic load of the road. I know how to create a map with the inverse distances to the nearest road and another with the traffic loads (this one only contains information in the pixels of the roads), but not a combination of both.

How can I do this?